# Error when trying to run parsing program using lex and yacc

Tags: linux, gcc, terminal, yacc, lex

i am trying to use lex and yacc for a laboratory on linux but i got an error. These are my 3 commands in the terminal:

`lex scan.l` -> generates lex.yy.c (the lexical analyser)

`yacc -d gram.y` -> generates y.tab.c (the syntactic analyser/parser);

`gcc -o C_PARSER lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ly -ll` but here i got an error it says :

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ly`

`collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

I have no idee why. Some ideas to solve this?

Comment: If using Ubuntu or Debian or the like, make sure the `bison-dev` package is installed.

Comment: Before i run these comands i have installed: sudo apt-get install bison and sudo apt-get install flex and i got no err. Only when i run the comand that i mentioned

Comment: shawn is suggesting that your run `sudo apt-get install bison-dev`, which is what you need on some debian/ubuntu systems in order to have `-ly`.

Comment: (E: Unable to locate package bison-dev) is the err if i try that

Comment: Sorry. I guess it's called `libbison-dev`.